# Shapefile for Colombian Cities with District / Borough level outlines

Tags: shapefile, data, colombia

I am looking for a shapefile for the city of Medellin and Bogota - Where it has the districts/Boroughs outlined

I have been on a both Colombian National gov and Local Gov sites, as well as official websites for the 2 city

But can not find exactly what I am looking for

I want to use it in QGIS, so that I can then place crime data onto it and create a heat map